# javascript check if string starts with some characters and remove those characters

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a string like `&:hello world` or `#helloworld` or `*helloworld`.

If a string starts with any of the characters like `&:` or `#` or `##` or `*` or any characters that I want to keep as special character.

For that I want to check if string starts with this characters and then remove this character. It should only be done if string starts with these character.

Is there any way I could do it simply without checking `string.startsWith` function for every characters.

Comment: Why not using regular expression ?

Comment: can you note do string.replace?

Comment: @jackstride string.replace will replace those characters from entire string. I just want to remove if the string starts with those characters.

Comment: @aryan I'm assuming you have this fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

It will return true or false based on it starts with special character

```
 !/^[A-Za-z0-9]/.test("#helloworld")
```

Comment: string.replace will replace those characters from entire string. I just want to remove if the string starts with those characters

Comment: may be more: (^\#+|\&+|\*+) if the characters are known.